# How to generate S3 expiring_url for custom host name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, paperclip

I have the S3 bucket (named 'img.example.com') and want to generate S3 expiring url with custom host name for paperclip attachment.
Code:

model:

```
#app/models/my_model.rb
...
has_attached_file :attachment, s3_url_options: { endpoint: 'img.example.com' }
...
```

config:

```
#config/initializers/paperclip.rb
...
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:s3_host_alias] = 'img.example.com'
...

#config/environments/development.rb
...
config.paperclip_defaults = {
  :storage => :s3,
  :s3_credentials => {
      :bucket => 'img.example.com',
      :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
      :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
  },
  :s3_permissions => :private
}
...
```

And #expiring_url generates this: "http://img.example.com/[bucket name]/[path]?[params]"

But i want it to generate url like this: "http://img.example.com/[path]?[params]"

rails 4.1
paperclip 4.1.1
aws-sdk 1.11.1

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `:url` in `config.paperclip_defaults`.  By default the url will use `":s3_path_url"` which includes the bucket. i.e. `<protocol>//<host_name>/<bucket>/<path>`

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
  ...
  :url => ":s3_alias_url"
  ...
}
```

This will generate a url in the format `<protocol>//<host_alias>/<path>`.

Comment: Yep. I defined Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:url] = ':s3_alias_url' but it doesn't help. I'm still receiving http://[bucket name].img.example.com/[path]?[params] or http://img.example.com/[bucket name]/[path]?[params]

Comment: Strange.  The option to set the host alias is actually `s3_host_alias` and not `s3_alias_host`; don't know if that makes any difference?

Comment: Sorry, then I don't know why it is not working.  You did restart your server?

Comment: Yes I did many times. I'm now experimenting with aws sdk s3. Trying to find the way to generate proper urls.

Comment: I think that this is not paperclip or aws-sdk issue. It's just a missing feature in aws-sdk: Users can't generate expiring_url for own website content hosted at S3.

Comment: Leaving the expiring_url out of it for a moment though it still seems there is a problem generating the url.  Despite setting ":s3_alias_url" you are getting a url in the default format ":s3_path_url" which from the code should only happen if the option [:url] is not specified.  expiring_url uses the same code as normal url, just with the addition of the s3_url_options.  Maybe try putting all the s3 configuration in one place?  At the moment you have both `default_options` and `config.paperclip_defaults.`